# Issue with creating Sharing rule using Spring'15 Metadata API version 33.0

Tags: metadata-api, spring15, sharing-rule

Has anyone tried creating Sharing rule using Spring'15 Metadata API version 33.0?

I want to create an owner based sharing rule using metadata and below is the code snippet method which is calling "MetadataService33" class created by Metadata WDSL.

```
public static void createSharingRule(String objectName, String ruleName, String ruleLabel, String groupName) {
    MetadataService33.MetadataPort stub = createService33();

    MetadataService33.SharingRules sharingRule = (MetadataService33.SharingRules) stub.readMetadata('SharingRules', new String[] { objectName }).getRecords()[0];

    //MetadataService33.SharingRules sharingRule = new MetadataService33.SharingRules();
    //sharingRule.fullName = objectName  ;

    MetadataService33.SharingCriteriaRule criteriaRuleOfObject = new MetadataService33.SharingCriteriaRule();
    MetadataService33.FilterItem criteriaItemOfRule = new MetadataService33.FilterItem();
    criteriaItemOfRule.operation = 'equals' ;
    criteriaRuleOfObject.criteriaItems = new List<MetadataService33.FilterItem> {criteriaItemOfRule} ;
    criteriaRuleOfObject.booleanFilter = 'False' ;
    MetadataService33.SharedTo sharedToGrpC = new  MetadataService33.SharedTo() ;
    criteriaRuleOfObject.sharedTo = sharedToGrpC ;


    MetadataService33.SharingTerritoryRule territoryRuleOfObject = new MetadataService33.SharingTerritoryRule();
    MetadataService33.SharedTo sharedFrmGrpT = new  MetadataService33.SharedTo() ;
    MetadataService33.SharedTo sharedToGrpT = new  MetadataService33.SharedTo() ;
    territoryRuleOfObject.sharedFrom = sharedFrmGrpT ;
    territoryRuleOfObject.sharedTo = sharedToGrpT ;


    MetadataService33.SharingOwnerRule ownerRuleOfObject = new MetadataService33.SharingOwnerRule();
    ownerRuleOfObject.fullName = ruleName ;
    ownerRuleOfObject.accessLevel = 'Edit' ;
    ownerRuleOfObject.label = ruleLabel ;

    MetadataService33.SharedTo sharedFrmGrp = new  MetadataService33.SharedTo() ; 
    sharedFrmGrp.group_x = new String[] {groupName} ; 

    MetadataService33.SharedTo sharedToGrp = new  MetadataService33.SharedTo() ;
    sharedToGrp.group_x = new String[] {groupName} ;

    ownerRuleOfObject.sharedFrom = sharedFrmGrp ;
    ownerRuleOfObject.sharedTo = sharedToGrp ;

    if(sharingRule.sharingOwnerRules != null)
        sharingRule.sharingOwnerRules.add(ownerRuleOfObject) ;
    else
        sharingRule.sharingOwnerRules =  new List<MetadataService33.SharingOwnerRule> {ownerRuleOfObject} ;

    if(sharingRule.sharingCriteriaRules == null)
        sharingRule.sharingCriteriaRules =  new List<MetadataService33.SharingCriteriaRule> {criteriaRuleOfObject} ;

    if(sharingRule.sharingTerritoryRules == null)
        sharingRule.sharingTerritoryRules = new List<MetadataService33.SharingTerritoryRule> {territoryRuleOfObject} ;

    MetadataService33.SaveResult[] resp = stub.updateMetadata(new MetadataService33.Metadata[] { sharingRule });
    // MetadataService33.SaveResult[] resp = stub.createMetadata(new MetadataService33.Metadata[] { sharingRule });
    // MetadataService33.UpsertResult[] resp = stub.upsertMetadata(new MetadataService33.Metadata[] { sharingRule });
    system.debug('====> ' + resp);
    handleSaveResults33(resp[0]);
}
```

When I call above method for a standard object like Contact, I get sucess message from salesforce though no rule is created in actual and when I call it for a custom object, I get unknow exception from saleforce. ReadMetadata call works perfectly fine and give proper result but updating sharing rule metadata gives me error.

Here is the code snippet how I call the method:

```
/* @1st parameter: Object API name
   @2nd parameter: Sharing rule name
   @3rd parameter: Sharing rule Label
   @4th parameter: Existing public group name
*/
MetadataWebserviceCall.createSharingRule('Contact', 'Test_Owner_Sharing_Rule2', 'Test Owner Sharing Rule2', 'AD_Sharing_Group');
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, owner based sharing rules are gone as of API Version 33.0. 
[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_meta.meta/api_meta/meta_ownersharingrule.htm) are the docs.

Quote here:

> This component is removed as of API version 33.0 and is available in earlier versions only.

However, it looks like you can use an alternative:
`SharingOwnerRule`.

> SharingOwnerRule
>   Defines a ownership-based sharing rule. It extends SharingBaseRule and inherits all its fields. Available in API version 33.0 and later.

Docs [here](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_sharingrules.htm#SharingOwnerRule).

Comment: Take a look at this:  https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=Spring-15-Metadata-API-changes&language=en_US... It says that individual sharing rule type deploying is not possible but you can deploy complete sharing rule and that is what I was trying with above code sample.